# base64 encoded html works in browser but not from shortcut on Android

Tags: android, html, base64, data-uri, data-uri-scheme

For IOS this is absolutely no problem but for Android I get "Application Not Installed"

The following simple html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> hello < p>
    </body>
</html>
```

encodes to a base64 html URI as:

data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUw+DQo8aHRtbCBsYW5nPSJlbi1VUyI+DQogICAgPGhlYWQ+DQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9oZWFkPg0KICAgIDxib2R5Pg0KICAgICAgICA8cD4gaGVsbG8gPC9wPg0KICAgIDwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4NCg==

if you cut and paste the html data URI above into an Android Browser (I tried several but including Chrome), it works perfectly well...i.e. it prints out hello onto the page.

Now, theoretically you should be able to manually create a home page shortcut icon to that data uri and then you should be able to click that shortcut icon and it should open a browser page and print "hello" as it does when you cut and paste it into the browser. And in fact, in IOS that is exactly what it does.

But in Android, I instead get "Application Not Installed". What application? Why doesn't it get recognized as a data uri and execute it in the default browser as it does in IOS? Are shortcuts to data URI's not allows in Android? Do I really need to configure Android somehow to recognize this as a data URI shortcut? Same problem even if it is a base64 encoded data image. Image works when I cut/paste it into the browser but not if I manually create a shortcut.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of WebViewClient method shouldOverrideUrlLoading must return false if url starts with data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64